# Is my owner react components state preventing me from updating child component state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update the state of a checkbox within a modal that is mounted via button on the UI. I'm loading the settings when AppWrapper mounts so I can pass them around as needed. Right now i'm just passing the settings as props to SettingsList component, which then renders a series of child nodes as checkboxes. I'm able to click the checkboxes when the modal is open, and the settings successfully save to the database. However when the modal is closed and reopened the settings are refreshed to the initially set state from the owner. Refreshing the page though shows the accurately checked boxes. That makes sense to me, but i'm unsure they best way to resolve it.

Should I/Can I update the state of the parent from the child setting so when the modal is reopened that passed props reflect the user changes?

My react structure looks like this:

```
<AppWrapper>
 getInitialState {settings:[]}
 <Modal>
  <SettingList settings={this.state.settings}>
   <Setting/>
  <SettingList/>
 <Modal/>
<AppWrapper/>
```

It's not direct one to one code, bust just a representation of the hierarchy.

My Modal component looks like this:

```
var Modal = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    if(this.props.isOpen){
      return (
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={this.props.transitionName} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>

        <div className="mymodal">
        {this.props.children}
        </div>
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      );
    } else {
      return <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={this.props.transitionName} transitionName={this.props.transitionName} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={500} />;
    }
  }
});
```

My SettingList component looks like this:

```
var SettingsList = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    var settingNodes = this.props.settings.map(function(setting, i){

      return (
        <Setting data={setting}
                  key={i}>
        </Setting>
      )
    }.bind(this));

    return (
      <div className="settings-block">
          <h2>Notifications</h2>
          <ul className="account-settings">
            {settingNodes}
          </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

And the Setting component looks like this:

```
var Setting = React.createClass({

  saveSetting: function(one) {

    core.setAccountSettings(this.refs.setting_checkbox.id, this.refs.setting_checkbox.checked).done(function(response){

      this.setState({
        defaultChecked:  this.refs.setting_checkbox.checked
      };

      console.log(response)
    }.bind(this));

  },

  render: function() {

    //get values from settings object
    for (var k in this.props.data) {
      this.settingId = k
      this.settingName = String(k.split(/_(.+)?/)[1]).replace(/_/g, " ");
      this.settingValue = (this.props.data[k].toLowerCase() == "true")
    }

    return (
      <li className="checkbox">
      <input onChange={this.saveSetting} ref="setting_checkbox" id={this.settingId} className="settings_checkbox" type="checkbox" defaultChecked={this.settingValue}></input>
      <label htmlFor={this.settingName}>{this.settingName}</label>
      </li>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: There are several issues with your code: e.g. `defaultChecked` is never used, you are also modifying `this` inside render (you could use local vars), ReactCSSTransitionGroup should wrap everything. But the core of your problem is that `this.state.settings` isn't updated. You could use callbacks in order to notify the parent components  of the updated settings or use a flux/redux/mobx store to maintain the state.

Comment: I've read a bit about flux and redux. I think I will look into redux a bit more before moving forward. Thank you for your insights.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the callback method a bit further, or link to some document with further details?

Comment: Here you have a comprehensive article explaining [8 different ways to communicate between components](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/), including callbacks.

Comment: Callbacks were the answer here. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments above there is a number of ways to pass data between components.

http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/

Following the article regarding callbacks was the solution for me.